# jQuery fetch typeform results using api

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get data from typeform's api using jQuery. I've been trying using $.ajax and $.getJSON but neither work.

I'm trying to get the completed response in a variable:

```
{
http_status: 200,
stats: {
responses: {
showing: 1000,
total: 1275,
completed: 369
}
},



$.getJSON( "<url here>", function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: if stats is your result, that is not a valid json. And server returns JSON header?

Comment: Any error on your console log?

Comment: If it succeed, then alert show you [object, object], change alert to console.log and check browser console what you see

Comment: try to put $.support.cors = true; before $.getJSON

Comment: It may appear if you run app which calling the remote source on local pc, try put to the webserver and call it from internet

Comment: What exactly do you mean by it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

This is the original answer from Typeform helpdesk.

> I'm afraid we don't support cross-origin requests, and **all
>   requests** to the Data API **have to be made from the
>   server-side**.
>  Please note, however, that we will be releasing
>   a suite of new APIs later this year, including a new version of the
>   Data API. And I'm sure that CORS and client-side requests will be
>   taken into consideration as part of the design process.
>  Sorry,
>   I can't bring you better news here, but I hope that answers your
>   question and please let me know if there's anything else I can help
>   you with!  
> Best Regards, 
> Support Team Typeform

So all requests you need call from server-side via `CURL` for example.
[Learn more](http://typeform.io/) how to do that.

You are probably confused from JSON but JSON is only data transfer format. Not everything what is a JSON is javascript api. Typeform uses data exchange via JSON format instead of XML.

Hope that helps and thank you helpdesk team for information